# Enter data into a master sheet (that has a date) that will transfer data to multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a worksheet that has a column of names and three different columns of dollar amounts.

```
                         Month:  January                        
                    Friday, January 02, 2015                        

Name   Check No.    T         O          S       TOTAL     Remarks
James            $154.00     $5.00      $2.00    $161.00    

Derek            $150.00     $3.00      $6.00    $159.00    

Samantha         $125.00     $10.00     $8.00    $143.00
```

I want to be able to get the data from the three columns to fill into named worksheets that has the date (from above) like so:
"James" Worksheet

```
          DATE               Tithes    Offering   Special 
Friday, January 02, 2015     154.00      5.00      2.00
```

But, I want to be able to enter a new date and the named worksheets start a new row with the current date and fill in the columns automatically each time I enter a date.

Is this possible in excel?

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is could be possible in Excel but As multiple sheets and tasks are involved, i believe,  you need an excel macro than simple functions.. 
try to record the activity and edit the macro as required.